# Why does np.linalg.lstsq not show me the residues? I checked the Paramater sizes but the second array is empty

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares

```
a_test = (Phi_train_M.T.dot(Phi_train_M) +lambda_reg*IdendityMatrix)
b_test = Phi_train_M.T.dot(data_train[:,1])
error_reg_test = np.linalg.lstsq (a_test,b_test,rcond=None)[1]
```

I want to check for the regularized sum of squared errors/residues. a_test dimensions are (16,16) and b_test dimensions are (16,) the doc says

> Blockquote
> residuals{(1,), (K,), (0,)} ndarray
> Sums of squared residuals: Squared Euclidean 2-norm for each column in b - a @ x. If the rank of a is < N or M <= N, this is an empty array. If b is 1-dimensional, this is a (1,) shape array. Otherwise the shape is (K,).

and as i typed it i noticed this doesnt work if 'a' is an N x N matrix. Does someone know a workaround? or how to solve this?

Comment: If the algorithm is still able to output a solution x, you can just compute the residual as res = |b - A*x|, where || is the norm.